# How can I make it so that when this button is pressed, the login section completely covers the registration section?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have an effect in css which means that when you press the "login" button, all its content overlaps the content of the registration section, but the login section does not cover the entire registration section, therefore, when you press the "login" button, when the window overlaps, you can still see a small part of the registration section. How can I make the login occupy the entire box when you press the button?

html and css annex

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slide Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/login.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">      
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="signup">
                <form>
                    
                    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="¿como te llamas?" required="">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder=" ingresa tu correo electronico" required="">
                    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="¿ingresa tu numero de telefono" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder=" crea una contraseña" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="repite tu contraseña" required="">
                    <a class="tyc" href="">terminos y condiciones</a>
                    <style>.tyc{
                        text-align: center;
                        justify-content: center;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        margin-left: 90px;  
                    }
                    </style>
                
                    <button class="register">REGISTRATE</button>
                    <style>.register{
                        margin-top: 7px;
                    }

                    </style>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="login">
                <form>
                    <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true">inicia sesion</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email " required="">
                    <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <button>Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e57373, #ffb74d, #cfd8dc);
}
.main{
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url("https://doc-08-2c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/68c90smiglihng9534mvqmq1946dmis5/fo0picsp1nhiucmc0l25s29respgpr4j/1631524275000/03522360960922298374/03522360960922298374/1Sx0jhdpEpnNIydS4rnN4kHSJtU1EyWka?e=view&authuser=0&nonce=gcrocepgbb17m&user=03522360960922298374&hash=tfhgbs86ka6divo3llbvp93mg4csvb38") no-repeat center/ cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 20px 50px #000;
}
#chk{
    display: none;
}
.signup{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    size: 70%;
}
label{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    margin: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
input{
    width: 60%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e0dede;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
button{
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    justify-content: center;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #573b8a;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{
    background: #6d44b8;
}
.login{
    height: 460px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 60% / 10%;
    transform: translateY(-180px);
    transition: .8s ease-in-out;
}
.login label{
    color: #573b8a;
    transform: scale(.6);
}

#chk:checked ~ .login{
    transform: translateY(-500px);
}
#chk:checked ~ .login label{
    transform: scale(1);    
}
#chk:checked ~ .signup label{
    transform: scale(.6);
}
```

thank you very much for your attention :)

I have tried modifying several values ​​within my css code and for now I have not found a solution :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the snippet below! Hope this helps.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e57373, #ffb74d, #cfd8dc);
}

.main {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("https://doc-08-2c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/68c90smiglihng9534mvqmq1946dmis5/fo0picsp1nhiucmc0l25s29respgpr4j/1631524275000/03522360960922298374/03522360960922298374/1Sx0jhdpEpnNIydS4rnN4kHSJtU1EyWka?e=view&authuser=0&nonce=gcrocepgbb17m&user=03522360960922298374&hash=tfhgbs86ka6divo3llbvp93mg4csvb38") no-repeat center/ cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 20px 50px #000;
}

#chk {
  display: none;
}

.signup {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  size: 70%;
}

label {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

input {
  width: 60%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #e0dede;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #573b8a;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: .2s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #6d44b8;
}

.login {
  height: 460px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 60% / 10%;
  transform: translateY(-180px);
  transition: .8s ease-in-out;
}

.login label {
  color: #573b8a;
  transform: scale(.6);
}

#chk:checked~.login {
  transform: translateY(-580px);
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#chk:checked~.login label {
  transform: scale(1);
}

#chk:checked~.signup label {
  transform: scale(.6);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Slide Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/login.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="signup">
      <form>

        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="¿como te llamas?" required="">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder=" ingresa tu correo electronico" required="">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="¿ingresa tu numero de telefono" required="">
        <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder=" crea una contraseña" required="">
        <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="repite tu contraseña" required="">
        <a class="tyc" href="">terminos y condiciones</a>
        <style>
          .tyc {
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 90px;
          }
        </style>

        <button class="register">REGISTRATE</button>
        <style>
          .register {
            margin-top: 7px;
          }
        </style>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="login">
      <form>
        <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true">inicia sesion</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email " required="">
        <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer, it really matters the most for new users like me.